# How do I list DNS server order in systemd-resolve?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I know that `systemd-resolve --status` lists all my connections and their DNS servers and `nmcli connection show <connection> | grep -i dns` will list the priority of the DNS connections. But is there a single command I can run that will list all DNS servers and their priority/order?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is stupid, but you can't!

`systemd-resolved` follows internal rules to choose the "correct" DNS. This might be different for each query. It uses things like if a server worked or failed in the past, interface order and even what domains allocated to each interface. It's difficult to manage with some VPN setups.

The best you can do is to `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` to see the `resolv.conf` file generated by `systemd-resolved`.

Comment: I also gave up and install dnsmasq with rules to resolve some domains in certain servers (ie: internal DNS to the internal network dns server). This solved my problems using several VPNs and dns resolve order

Comment: Why o why am I not surprised that linux developers, who after 20 years still can't make a properly functional desktop that isn't littered with bugs and inconsistencies, can't make a properly functional command line interface also. It's so depressing. Open Sores indeed.

Comment: @ChristopherThomas notice that all OS have weak and strong points, having used both windows and macosX, i can tell you that they both have lot of stupid "features" in the DNS. I understand that systemd was developed for the clueless user and it tries to guess things... but still, not all users are clueless and having only that operating node is stupid.The problem is that there is no "one size fits all" and that is why all OS have major issues with managing DNS. That being said, while not perfect, IMHO, linux is still a much better OS and desktop than the other two, and it's free and open

Comment: systemd's command line interface is absolute garbage. It lacks many features that would be useful for people building interfaces to automate and control a linux system through user interfaces, etc. But it just doesn't have them. They only implemented the basic functionalities and missed a lot of what actual system administrators need. We don't want to parse weird and wacky command line outputs using sed or grep for some value. I expect to be able to query the value and get it directly. It's absolute garbage. Even knowledgable administrators suffer to get useful information out of it.

Comment: and by the way, mac does not have problems managing DNS and has had a consistent command line interface for years already and it's stable and reliable. So your claim that all OS have this issue is false. Windows also has a stable way to interact with it's networking system through the command line. Linux is the only one out of those three with problems.

Comment: `systemd-resolv` got self-awareness,
it just doing things, not care what you want

Comment: @ChristopherThomas there's no way you just implied Windows has a better CLI experience than Linux 

Comment: You're right, I didn't imply that. What I said was that the windows tools to interacting with the network subsystem is at least stable and useful without parsing text for little snippets of text in a fragile way which linux requires to do the same job

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a  dns priority with

```
nmcli -p connection modify MY_VPN_CONNECTION ipv4.dns-priority -42
```

as taken from https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6076